# How do you separate the meanings of synonymous words?

Tags: syntax, methods, naming-conventions

I apologize if this is not the right forum for this question. Please direct me to the right one if not.

When I write functions I'm always plagued by which synonym of a word to use when naming the function. How do you guys differentiate? Are there subtle differences that I'm missing?

Examples:

```
Getters        - get, at, retrieve, fetch, from
Setters        - set, insert, put, add
Concatenation  - concat, merge
Threading      - sync/asynch, threaded, worker
```

I'm probably forgetting a bunch, but you should be able to get the idea. Thanks!

As an example answer: `from` is different from `get` in that it suggests getting a range of values. What about the rest though?

Comment: The verbiage used is less important than your consistency of using whatever terms you chose.

Comment: This was discussed before in the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151418/determining-which-verb-to-use-for-method-names-in-java/7151808#7151808

Comment: @suat there was no answer there about the differences that I point out. `Retrieving data: get or retrieve` is part of the answer posted. I want to know whether syntactically there is a difference between the things that I pointed out.

Comment: @chacham15 ok, posted my opinions in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think each verb has its own convenient case to be used. I would use them as follows:
**Getters**
**get:** Single object retrieval
**at:** Single item retrieval from a collection
**retrieve,fetch,from,obtain:** Any object, stream retrieval from a distant location

**Setters**
(Same convention in Java)
**set:** Single object assignment
**insert:** An item addition to a collection possibly with an index
**put:** An item addition to a collection without considering the index
**add:** An item addition to beginning or end of a collection

**Concatenation**
**concat:** Appending of two objects one after another
**merge:** Merging two collections possibly requiring a more complex processing than concatenation
**Deletion**
**delete**: Any deletion operation requiring a complex processing
**remove,removeAt**: Deletion an object from a collection possibly with an index
**pop**: Deletion from a stack,queue

and so on...